# Making Java Server to stop after certain time

Tags: java, server

I want to create a Java Server program that stops after 10 seconds.Right now, I am using setSoTimeout method. Once the time expires, I catch the exception and generate a Server Closing Message.

But that seems to be a workaround. Is there a better way to do it?

```
public class DailyAdviceServer
{
String[] adviceList = {"Take smaller bites", "Go for the tight jeans. No they do NOT make you look fat",
    "One word: inappropriate", "Just for today, be honest.  Tell your boss what you *really* think", 
    "You might want to rethink that haircut"};

public void startserver() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(2727);
        serverSock.setSoTimeout(10000);
        while (true)
        {  
            Socket sock = serverSock.accept();
            OutputStreamWriter streamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(streamwriter);

            String advice = getAdvice();
            writer.write(advice);
            writer.close();
        }


    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("The Server has now shut down.");
    }
     catch(IOException ex)
    {
         ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}

private String getAdvice() {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * adviceList.length);
    return adviceList[random];
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DailyAdviceServer server = new DailyAdviceServer();
    server.startserver();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can start a timer after the creation of the ServerSocket and when the timer expires you can close it